# Was bedeutet „unterliegt starken Schwankungen“?

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet „unterliegt starken Schwankungen“?

1. ist abhängig von starken Schwankungen
2. einfach schwanken

Answer (score 1):

Es bedeutet, dass ein Wert **langfristig** oder **systematisch** stark schwankt. Meist ist es aber nur eine gehobene Formulierung.

> Der Wasserstand im Wattenmeer unterliegt starken Schwankungen durch Ebbe und Flut.

Folgender Satz bedeutet inhaltlich dasselbe:

> Der Wasserstand im Wattermeer schwankt wegen Ebbe und Flut stark.

Comment: Wieso langfristig oder systematisch? Etwas kann nicht kurzfristig starken Schwankungen unterliegen? Oder unsystematischen, starken Schwankungen?

Comment: "Langfristig" ist vielleicht übertrieben, aber bei einem *einmaligen* Ereignis würde ich nicht von "unterliegt Schwankungen" sprechen (also "Die Laterne schwankte, als der Wagen beim Einparken anstieß" und nicht "... unterlag Schwankungen ...").

Comment: @Uwe: Langfristig ist nicht übertrieben, sondern der falsche Begriff. Schwankungen können extrem langsam sein - man denke an die Achse von Planeten beim Lauf um ihre Zentralgestrine. Langfristige Börsenkurse würde ich als etwas, das man in Jahrzehnten misst, betrachten. Börsenkursschwankungen können aber auch sehr viel kurzfristigeren Ereignissen unterliegen. Die Frist muss aber mehr als eine Wellenlänge umfassen, wenn man von Schwankungen in Mz. spricht, das natürlich schon.

Comment: @Janka schrieb "gehobene Formulierung". Für mich geht eine solche Formulierung ein wenig in Richtung Funktionsverbgefüge und Verwaltungsdeutsch, was ich als nicht unbedingt sehr gutes Deutsch empfinde. Allerdings sind hier die Möglichkeiten eingeschränkt: _Es gibt starke Schwankungen_ ist zu banal, und die Längerfristigkeit fehlt, und auch bei _schwankt/schwanken stark_ müsste so etwas wie 'im Zeitverlauf' hinzugefügt werden. Anders gesagt: 'Schwankungen unterliegen' bedeutet 'im Zeitverlauf schwanken', wobei die Schwankungsbreite einkalkuliert ist.

Answer (score 1):

Das zweite ist richtig: Etwas ist starken Schwankungen ausgesetzt.

Die Stromproduktion in einem Gezeitenkraftwerk ist abhängig von starken (Wasserstands-) Schwankungen, unterliegt diesen aber nicht.

> Der Vanillepreis unterliegt seit den bürgerkriegsähnlichen Zuständen
>   auf Madagaskar starken Schwankungen.

Der Preis ist zwar von der politischen Stabilität abhängig, aber nicht von deren Schwankungen.